# How to disable switching to explorer activity bar when call openTextDocument? VScode

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating an extension for vscode. At some point I need to open a file. I use `vscode.workspace.openTextDocument` for that and it's working, but switchs activity bar from custom to Explorer. I want to leave my custom activity bar opened. How can I do that?

I have tried closing all activity bars except mine, searching for some settings(nothing found), tried to use `vscode.commands.executeCommand` with `workbench.view`, but there are only `workbenck.view.explorer` and `workbench.view.extensions`.

```
select(node: json.Node) {
    var setting: vscode.Uri = vscode.Uri.parse('file:///home/user/some_file');
    vscode.workspace.openTextDocument(setting).then((a: vscode.TextDocument) => {
        vscode.window.showTextDocument(a, 1, false).then(e => {
            // move to 96 line in the file. Just for example.
            let range_n = e.document.lineAt(96).range;
            e.selection =  new vscode.Selection(range_n.start, range_n.end);
            e.revealRange(range_n);
        })
    }, (error: any) => {
        console.error(error);
        debugger;
    }); 
}
```

I expect that my custom activity bar and necessary file will be open after running select. Now file is opened, but activity bar is switched to explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no idea, how exactly the problem was solved, but now it works as it should be.

I can assume, that the key here is another plugin (let's call it plugin_2, and main - plugin_1). I have another plugin (plugin_2), which runs when some file opens and draw some result into outline, so probably, when I relocate plugin_2 into my custom activity bar from explorer, and open a file with main plugin_1, plugin_2 ran and didn't let explorer open.

I believe that is the decision. Hope it will help someone.